# Need advice on backing up my entire parity directory

Tags: parity, backup

I'm developing a blockchain explorer and I want to backup my parity directory on Ubuntu. I've been pointed to directions on the Parity wiki for backing up but it only provides backup instructions for backing up my keys. I wish to backup my entire ".local/share/io.parity.ethereum" directory.
I'm thinking of just using rsync to backup that directory (after stopping parity with the command: "sudo systemctl stop io.parity.ethereum"). Has anyone done this to know if this should work well for copying over the entire parity directory? Any input would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

```
rsync -avzh $HOME/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/ /path/to/my/backup/parity
```

If you want to export the keys only, they are located in:

```
$HOME/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/keys
```

And if you want the blockchain or state only, you can directly export it via:

```
parity export blocks /path/to/chain
parity export state /path/to/state
```

Hope that clarifies everything.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for taking the time to answer that and offer the additional comments, that is very helpful! I really do appreciate it!